# Restricting background-size: contain to the original image size

Tags: css

I'm writing a photo-album, and the photo's are displayed in a page-covering div using the following CSS:

```
.photoHolder {
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(theImage.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    [...]
}
```

If the original image is smaller than the size of `photoHolder`, the image is stretched and looks ropey. Is there a way of stopping this without using JavaScript to restrict the size of the div?

The photo sizes, of course, can vary, as can the size of `photoHolder` (as it takes up most of the available window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove

```
background-size: contain;
```

which is causing the background image to stretch.

Comment: Correct. From MDN, `contain` is ... *This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.* Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: I need 'contain' in there to make sure the image fits on the page if it's big. It looks like the answer to the question is "no", then. Thanks, both!